# Why first row of the grid has a double size?

Tags: css, css-grid

The first row of my grid has a double row size. Why is this happening? How might it be possible to create an area which contains two columns and one row of the normal size?

[Picture Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j9Ru.png)

Video displaying the problem: https://youtu.be/ahfjeJXz-nY

Using these styles:

```
.gallery {
    margin: 0px 16px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 10fr);
    grid-gap: 27px;
    grid-template-areas: 'normal normal . .';
}
.item {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the first row contains at least one element that increases the size of it and then increases the size of the whole row. If all items were empty, they would all be the same size.

Comment: Thank you. I'm decrease row height to 50% and it is working good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you leave an empty space between the track values, the grid lines are automatically assigned positive and negative numbers

```
.container {
      grid-template-columns: 40px 50px auto 50px 40px;
      `grid-template-rows: 25% 100px auto;`
}
```